# cocoa : how to set background color of a view as light green color in cocoa without using CALayer?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want to set the background color of the view without using CALayer.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 5):

You didn't specify if you're talking about AppKit (OSX) or UIKit (iOS). I'll asume you're talking about AppKit because most people coming from UIKit run into this.

NSView does not natively draw a background or background color. You have to either subclass NSView and draw your own color in `drawRect`, OR use NSBox provided in AppKit which does draw a background.

If you subclass NSView, then your `drawRect` method may look like this:

```
- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [[NSColor blackColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
}
```

If you decide to use NSBox, then you can set the background color this way:

```
[myBox setFillColor:[NSColor blackColor]];
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want a call to `super` when overriding `-drawRect:`?

Comment: No there is no default implementation in NSView. This method is intended for subclasses.

Comment: Ah ok. I mainly deal with UIKit and Foundation, so this was kinda screaming at me :)